# get array value from $$variable[0] (value of array)

Tags: php, arrays

i have a problem on PHP

i have some array

```
$hp = array('samsung', 'iphone', 'blackberry');

$samsung = array(array('Tab', 3,2),array('Note', 4), array('Mini', 5, 6, 8));
$iphone = array(array('2G', 2, 3, 6),array('4S', 5), array('5', 2,2), array('3GS', 2,7));
$blackberry = array(array('onix', 2),array('curve', 2, 6), array('armstrong', 5), array('gemini', 8. 1));
```

i need to count value from list of type of hp ($hp), and i have try this but fail;

```
for($p=0; $p=count($hp); $p++){ //this ok can get count of $hp = 3
    for($i=0; $i=count($$hp[$p]); $i++){ //this ok can get count of type from $hp[index], if samsung = 3, if iphone= 4, if blackberry = 4
        for($u=0; $i=count($$hp[$p][$i]); $u++){ //this fail to get count the next level of hp type, should be if samsung[0] = 3, samsung[1] = 2, samsung[2]=4 
            //any code here
        }
   }
}
```

can someone help me??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [foreach loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) would be a bit easier to deal with here, so that you don't have to deal with so many iterators/numbers - and you can easily assign nicely named variables to work with at each level, e.g. phone, model, specification, feature etc. You also only have to deal with one [variable variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) this way.

Try this:

```
foreach($hp as $phone) {
    echo 'Phone: ' . $phone . PHP_EOL;
    foreach($$phone as $model) {
        foreach($model as $value) {
            echo 'Value: ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

[See it working](https://eval.in/122849)

---

**Note:** there's a `.` instead of a `,` in your `$blackberry` array example.

Answer (score 1):

As with so many cases where people *think* they need "variable variables" (`$$something`), what you actually want here is an associative array:

```
$phones = array(
    'samsung' => array(array('Tab', 3,2),array('Note', 4), array('Mini', 5, 6, 8)),
    'iphone' => array(array('2G', 2, 3, 6),array('4S', 5), array('5', 2,2), array('3GS', 2,7)),
    'blackberry' = array(array('onix', 2),array('curve', 2, 6), array('armstrong', 5), array('gemini', 8, 1))
);
```

Now your `$hp` array isn't representing a set of variable names, it's representing keys in a data structure, which makes a lot more sense.  (What if, later, you want to store those lists in a database, or a config file? You should be the one choosing variable names, not your program.)

As [`scrowler` points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22493807/157957), you can also make use of a `foreach` rather than a `for` loop to end up with more readable code:

```
$phones_wanted = array('samsung', 'iphone', 'blackberry');

foreach($phones_wanted as $phone_key) {
    echo 'Phone: ', $phone_key, PHP_EOL;

    // This is the point where you thought you needed a variable variable, but don't
    foreach($phones[$phone_key] as $model) {

        echo 'Model: ', $model, PHP_EOL;
        foreach($model as $value) {
            echo 'Value: ', $value, PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've also used much more meaningful variable names. Your original bug was that you were using `$i` in two different loops. It's a lot easier to read:

```
for ($model_index=1; $model_index=count($phones_wanted[$phone_index][$model_index]); $model_index++)
```

than:

```
for($i=0; $i=count($$hp[$p][$i]); $i++){
```

Comment: thanks for answer... actual code is different loop, i just wrong when i retype to SO..

Comment: @Hans It's important to always test that sample code you provide reproduces the actual problem. And I stand by my main point here that "variable variables" are almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You're not accessing the array correctly for the count.  You would need to use `$i` instead of `$u`.  Also, you are overriding the variable `$i` again with `$i=count($$hp[$p][$u]);`.  Plus, I think you are looking for `<` instead of `=` for `$i=count($$hp[$p][$i]);` and the others:

```
for($p=0; $p<count($hp); $p++){ //this ok can get count of $hp = 3
    for($i=0; $i<count($$hp[$p]); $i++){ //this ok can get count of type from $hp[index], if samsung = 3, if iphone= 4, if blackberry = 4
        for($u=0; $u<count($$hp[$p][$i]); $u++){ //this fail to get count the next level of hp type, should be if samsung[0] = 3, samsung[1] = 2, samsung[2]=4 
            //any code here
        }
   }
}
```

As **IMSoP** suggested, you may want to use more *detailed* variable names that aren't one letter to avoid future mistakes.

Comment: Although this is technically the right answer, I can't bring myself to up-vote an answer that advocates replacing a variable called `$i` with one called `$x` rather than renaming the variables to something actually meaningful.

Comment: sory anonymous, actual in my code is defferent, i just wrong when i re-type.. but thanks

Comment: @IMSoP I don't feel that I need to have them change their style of coding.  They may use comments instead of detailed variable names or something else.

Comment: @Anonymous I guess my feeling was that in this case the poor choice of variable names was actually contributing to the bug, so it was kind of relevant to the solution.

Comment: @IMSoP I see what you're saying.  I added it in as a possibility.